# Filling unusual shapes in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fill, python-turtle

I am trying to make the Disney intro in turtle, but this part of the castle doesn't want to fill properly and I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```py
import turtle

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()

background_color = "#1b3f9f"
castle_color = "#78b3d3"

def goto_168_64():
    t1.penup()
    t2.penup()
    t1.goto(168,64)
    t2.goto(-168,64)
    t1.pendown()
    t2.pendown()

def background():
    t1.hideturtle()
    t2.hideturtle()
    turtle.bgcolor(background_color)

def draw():
    goto_168_64()
    t1.fillcolor(castle_color)
    t2.fillcolor(castle_color)
    t1.begin_fill()
    t2.begin_fill()
    t1.goto(40,64)
    t2.goto(-40,64)
    t1.setheading(90)
    t2.setheading(90)
    for x in range(23):
        t1.forward(2)
        t2.forward(2)
        t1.left(4)
        t2.right(4)
    t1.setheading(180)
    t2.setheading(0)
    t1.forward(25)
    t2.forward(25)
    goto_168_64()
    t1.setheading(180)
    t2.setheading(0)
    for x in range(23):
        t1.forward(2)
        t2.forward(2)
        t1.right(4)
        t2.left(4)
    t1.setheading(90)
    t2.setheading(90)
    t1.forward(10)
    t2.forward(10)
    t1.setheading(180)
    t2.setheading(0)
    t1.forward(140)
    t2.forward(140)
    t1.penup()
    t2.penup()
    t1.goto(0,103)
    t2.goto(0,103)
    t1.pendown()
    t2.pendown()
    t1.goto(0,93)
    t2.goto(0,93)
    t1.end_fill()
    t2.end_fill()

background()
draw()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code is better readable for most people if variables and functions are in English instead of another language. I translated it for you, based on the explanation you provided. For your next question, please do this yourself, to make it easier for others to understand your question. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get what you want with one less turtle and a dozen fewer lines of code if we think of this as a single polygon:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

background_color = "#1b3f9f"
castle_color = "#78b3d3"

def draw():
    t1.penup()
    t1.goto(168, 64)
    t1.pendown()

    t1.begin_fill()

    t1.setheading(180)
    t1.forward(128)
    t1.setheading(90)

    for _ in range(23):
        t1.forward(2)
        t1.left(4)

    t1.setheading(180)
    t1.forward(11)

    for _ in range(23):
        t1.forward(2)
        t1.left(4)

    t1.setheading(180)
    t1.forward(128)
    t1.setheading(0)

    for _ in range(23):
        t1.forward(2)
        t1.left(4)

    t1.setheading(90)
    t1.forward(10)
    t1.setheading(0)
    t1.forward(264)
    t1.setheading(270)
    t1.forward(10)

    for _ in range(23):
        t1.forward(2)
        t1.left(4)

    t1.end_fill()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor(background_color)

t1 = Turtle()
t1.hideturtle()
t1.fillcolor(castle_color)

draw()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image: output]

You might be able to reduce the above code further by using a variable (or variables) for the relative drawing direction and repeating half the code in loop.